# Unplugging power bank usb safely

Tags: usb

I have a strange question, but please bear with me.

Mostly I charge a power bank via usb in my laptop. When I want to unplug it, Windows does not show a "Safely remove hardware" option and icon in the system tray.

Is it safe to often use a power bank in USB and unplugging it right away (without safely removing hardware)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure power bank only uses the power pins on the USB connector.  If the device doesn't respond to queries from the USB controller with a device type (storage, HID, etc), then the OS (Windows) doesn't know or care that there's a device there.  So no "remove hardware" option is available.

So yes, you can just plug it in and unplug it as needed.

Comment: ok thanks, straight to the point

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no solid-state drive to corrupt, you don't need to worry about the safety of the power bank or corrupting it. It's just power based, and the "remove hardware" option is just to ensure there is no data exchange going on while you remove the drive, which is what could potentially corrupt a drive.